# How should you handle complex filters in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am working on a project where i have a large amount of content to display. Because i dont want the page to be overflown with content i divided it into pages of 6 posts. I also want to implement a filtering system with a searchbar, difficultyslider and categories.

I got everything working but i am stuck with making the pagination work. This is because i need the length of the final filtered array so i know when to jump back to page 1. The problem is i do all the filtering inside the return statement of my component and need a way to do it above. That way i can just map over the filtered array instead of needing to use 3 filter functions. The component will also be way easier to read and split up because at the moment its pretty much chaos.

[image of the final product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN6G7.jpg)

these are the arrays which are imported from other files

```
export const filterKeys = [
  "all",
  "airtricks",
  "spins",
  "flips",
  "grabs",
  "obstacles",
  "dock",
];

export const difficulties = [
  {
    name: "Beginner",
    color: "var(--light-blue)",
    bgColor: "var(--light-blue-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "Novice",
    color: "var(--lime-green)",
    bgColor: "var(--lime-green-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "Intermediate",
    color: "var(--dark-yellow)",
    bgColor: "var(--dark-yellow-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "Advanced",
    color: "var(--light-orange)",
    bgColor: "var(--light-orange-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "Expert",
    color: "var(--dark-orange)",
    bgColor: "var(--dark-orange-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "Pro",
    color: "var(--dark-red)",
    bgColor: "var(--dark-red-bg)",
  },
  {
    name: "All difficulties",
    color: "var(--p-col)",
  },
];
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import {
  HiOutlineChevronDoubleRight,
  HiOutlineChevronDoubleLeft,
} from "react-icons/hi";

import { urlFor, client } from "../../client";
import { Wrapper } from "../../wrapper";
import { difficulties, filterKeys } from "../../constants";

import "./Tricklist.scss";

const Tricklist = () => {
  // tricklist states
  const [currentDifficulty, setCurrentDifficulty] = useState(7);
  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState("All");
  const [filteredTricks, setFilteredTricks] = useState([]);
  const [tricks, setTricks] = useState([]);

  // searchbar states
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: "" });
  const { name } = formData;

  // pagination states
  const [tricksPerPage] = useState(6);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const indexOfLastTrick = currentPage * tricksPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstTrick = indexOfLastTrick - tricksPerPage;

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "tricks"]';
    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setTricks(data);
      setFilteredTricks(data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleDifficulty = (difficulty) => {
    setCurrentDifficulty(difficulty + 1);
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleFilter = (item) => {
    setActiveFilter(item);

    if (item === "all") {
      setFilteredTricks(tricks);
    } else {
      setFilteredTricks(tricks.filter((trick) => trick.tags.includes(item)));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app__tricklist">
      <div className="app__tricklist-filters">
        <h3 className="heading-text">
          Trick <span className="highlighted">List</span>
        </h3>
        <p className="sub-heading">Filters</p>

        <div className="filters-panel">
          <div className="top-row">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Trick Name"
              value={name}
              onChange={handleChangeInput}
              name="name"
              className="searchbar"
            />

            <div className="difficulty-slider">
              <h4>
                Difficulty:
                <span
                  style={{
                    color: `${difficulties[currentDifficulty - 1].color}`,
                  }}
                >
                  {difficulties[currentDifficulty - 1].name}
                </span>
              </h4>
              <ul className="dots">
                {difficulties.map((difficulty, index) => (
                  <div
                    key={difficulty.name}
                    className="dot"
                    onClick={() => handleDifficulty(index)}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: `${
                        index < currentDifficulty
                          ? difficulties[currentDifficulty - 1].color
                          : "var(--white)"
                      }`,
                    }}
                  />
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="bottom-row">
            <ul className="category-filters">
              {filterKeys.map((filterKey, index) => (
                <motion.button
                  whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1], x: [200, 0] }}
                  transition={{ duration: 0.5, delay: index * 0.1 }}
                  key={filterKey}
                  onClick={() => handleFilter(filterKey)}
                  className={`${
                    activeFilter === filterKey ? "active-filter" : ""
                  }`}
                >
                  {filterKey}
                </motion.button>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {tricks && (
        <ul className="app__tricklist-list">
          {filteredTricks
            .filter((trick) => {
              if (
                trick.difficulty === currentDifficulty ||
                currentDifficulty === 7
              ) {
                return trick;
              }
            })
            .filter((trick) => {
              if (formData.name === "") {
                return trick;
              } else if (
                trick.name.toLowerCase().includes(formData.name.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return trick;
              }
            })
            .slice(indexOfFirstTrick, indexOfLastTrick)
            .map((trick) => (
              <motion.li
                key={trick.name}
                className="app__tricklist-card"
                whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1], y: [300, 0] }}
                transition={{
                  duration: 0.3,
                  ease: "easeOut",
                }}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              >
                <img src={urlFor(trick.image)} alt={trick.name} />

                <div className="card-body">
                  <div className="card-header">
                    <h4>{trick.name}</h4>
                    <p
                      className="difficulty-rating uppercase"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                          difficulties[trick.difficulty - 1].bgColor,
                        color: difficulties[trick.difficulty - 1].color,
                      }}
                    >
                      {difficulties[trick.difficulty - 1].name}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <p className="p-text">{trick.description}</p>
                </div>
              </motion.li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      )}

      <div className="app__tricklist-pagination">
        <button
          className="prev-btn"
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}
        >
          <HiOutlineChevronDoubleLeft />
          prev
        </button>
        <button
          className="next-btn"
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}
        >
          next
          <HiOutlineChevronDoubleRight />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper(Tricklist, "Trick-List");
```

Comment: use `grid` css, then you dont need to handle overflow or implement work around logic

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen could you explain a little bit futher. Do you mean the pagination or something else because i cant find anything about pagination with css grid

Comment: you would need to use grid with some custom js, but to save you a headache, just use ReactJs and use statemanagement with condidtional rendering